# Convert Array to List in SML

Tags: sml

How do i convert an `array` type to a `list` type in sml.  I have searched the list and array structure functions but have not found one that does this (there is a list to array function though).

Description of List structure:
http://sml-family.org/Basis/list.html

Description of Array structure:
http://sml-family.org/Basis/array.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While there isn't a built in direct conversion function, you could use `Array.foldr` to quite easily construct a corresponding list:

```
fun arrayToList arr = Array.foldr (op ::) [] arr
```

Example:

```
- val arr = Array.fromList [6, 3, 5, 7];
val arr = [|6,3,5,7|] : int array

- val ls = arrayToList arr;
val ls = [6,3,5,7] : int list
```

Answer (score 5):

There doesn't seem to be a built-in `List.fromArray` or `Array.toList`. It looks like the easiest way to define it would be

```
List.tabulate(Array.length(arr), fn i => Array.sub(arr, i))
```

So...

```
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.76 [built: Thu Feb 19 00:37:13 2015]
- val arr = Array.fromList([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) ;;
[autoloading]
[library $SMLNJ-BASIS/basis.cm is stable]
[autoloading done]
val arr = [|1,2,3,4,5|] : int array

- fun listFromArray arr = List.tabulate(Array.length(arr), fn i => Array.sub(arr, i)) ;;
[autoloading]
[autoloading done]
val listFromArray = fn : 'a array -> 'a list

- listFromArray(arr) ;;
val it = [1,2,3,4,5] : int list

-
```